# How do I sort an array of JObjects in VB.net

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, sorting

I am working in VB.net (4.5) and using the Newtonsoft Json Linq package.

I have an array (BuyList) composed of 100 market orders in the format:

{{
  "Quantity": 0.14333804,
  "Rate": 6693.01
}}

I would like to sort the array by "Rate" values from low to high.

Here is how I am creating the array:

```
Dim BuyList As Array = BittrexResponse("result")("buy").Children().ToArray()
```

BittrexResponse is a JObject created from parsing an Http request.

I have been trying to use:

```
Array.sort(BuyList)
```

Which throws an error stating failed to compare two elements in the array and that at least one element must implement IComparable.  How do I specify that I want to compare all "Rate" values and sort them from low to high?

Comment: Why not deserialize to NET objects and collections (like a `List(Of T)`) so you can do anything you want to it?

Comment: Mostly ignorance.  I'm self taught in programming and knew nothing of lists 24hrs ago.  I have large gaps in my knowledge, most of what I know is from ideas I think of that require software which is how I learn.  There is such a sea of information on the web; it makes learning to program a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sort an array of any type in exactly the same way.  If the elements don't implement `IComparable` the the `Sort` method has no idea how to compare them in order to sort them, so you have to tell it.  How would you normally get that `Rate` value from such an object and what type is it?  I'm guessing that you'd use the `Item` property and that it is either `Double` or `Decimal`.  You need to tell the `Sort` method that, e.g.

```
Array.sort(BuyList, Function(jo1, jo2) CDec(jo1.Item("Rate")).CompareTo(CDec(jo2.Item("Rate"))))
```

That's using the overload that takes a `Comparison(Of T)` delegate.  Such a delegate refers to a method that, given two array elements, will compare them in a specific way and return an `Integer` value that indicates their relative order.  That usually comes down to calling one or more `CompareTo` methods of types that do implement `IComparable`, as `Decimal` does.

Comment: Thanks!  I was running into similar solutions on other web pages.   Some talk of creating classes to house methods to sort iLists since I guess iList and List are without the same methods.  

I initially started with iLists then went to arrays but finally found a solution using what you described using lists again.  Here is my working code:

`Dim BuyList As List(Of JToken) = BittrexResponse("result")("buy").Children().ToList()`
                                                                    
`BuyList.Sort(Function(jo1, jo2) CDec(jo1.Item("Rate")).CompareTo(CDec(jo2.Item("Rate"))))`